# How do I take the squared difference of two Keras tensors?

Tags: keras

I have a Keras `Model` which calculates two tensors, `r1` and `r2` of the same shape. I would like to have the model calculate `(r1 - r2)**2`.

I can take the sum of these tensors with `keras.layers.add(r1, r2)`. I can take a product with `keras.layers.multiply(r1, r2)`. If there was a `subtract` function, I'd write

```
r = keras.layers.subtract(r1, r2)
square_diff = keras.layers.multiply(r, r)
```

but there doesn't appear to be a `keras.layers.subtract` function.

In lieu of that I've been trying to figure out how to multiply one of my inputs by a constant -1 tensor and then adding, but I can't figure out how to create that -1 tensor. I've tried a number of variants on

```
negative_one = keras.backend.constant(np.full(r1.get_shape()), -1)
```

none of which work. Presumably because the dimensionality of `r1` is `(?, 128)` (i.e. the first dimension is a batch size, and the second represents 128 hidden elements.)

What is the correct way in Keras to take the difference of two tensors?

Comment: [Keras 2.0.7](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/releases/tag/2.0.7) now includes a `subtract` layer function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not qualified to say whether or not this is the correct way, but the following code will calculate `(r1 - r2)**2` as you request.  The key enabler here is the use of the Keras functional API and [Lambda](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layers to invert the sign of an input tensor.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import add

r1 = Input(shape=(1,2,2))
r2 = Input(shape=(1,2,2))

# Lambda for subtracting two tensors
minus_r2 = Lambda(lambda x: -x)(r2)
subtracted = add([r1,minus_r2])
out= Lambda(lambda x: x**2)(subtracted)

model = Model([r1,r2],out)

a = np.arange(4).reshape([1,1,2,2])
b = np.ones(4).reshape([1,1,2,2])

print(model.predict([a,b]))
# [[[[ 1.  0.]
#    [ 1.  4.]]]]

print((a-b)**2)
# [[[[ 1.  0.]
#    [ 1.  4.]]]]
```

Comment: @dhinckley Great answer. My question is how to perform the same operation i.e. subtraction and squaring for series of tensors. So, for example, the output from lstm layer?

Answer (score 9):

As dhinckley mentioned, you should use Lambda layer. But I would suggest to define your custom function first. With this code will a little bit more clear:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda

def squared_differences(pair_of_tensors):
    x, y = pair_of_tensors
    return K.square(x - y)

square_diff = Lambda(squared_differences)([r1, r2])
```