# Concatenating hidden units using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, nlp

I am trying to concatenate the hidden units. For example, I have `3` units, `h1,h2,h3` then I want the new layer to have `[h1;h1],[h1;h2],[h1;h3],[h2;h1]...`.

So, I have tried:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self,W_regularizer=None,W_constraint=None, **kwargs):
        self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')
        self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    assert len(input_shape) == 3
    # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
    self.W = self.add_weight((input_shape[-1],input_shape[-1]),
                             initializer=self.init,
                             name='{}_W'.format(self.name),
                             regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                             constraint=self.W_constraint,
                            trainable=True)
    super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, x,input_shape):
    conc=K.concatenate([x[:, :-1, :], x[:, 1:, :]],axis=1)# help needed here
    uit = K.dot(conc, self.W)# W has input_shape[-1],input_shape[-1]
    return uit

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return input_shape[0], input_shape[1],input_shape[-1]
```

I am not sure what should I return for the second argument of my output shape.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, LSTM
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda

lstm=LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(input)
something=MyLayer()(lstm)
```

Comment: Could you please post reproducible code and provide an example of the expected output?

Comment: @rvinas I have edited the question. Will that work? I am not sure how to show you the output. I have already mentioned how I want the tensors to be concatenated.

Comment: @rvinas It will be okay even if I can get the exhaustive concatenation like `h1;h1,h1;h2,h1;h3,h2;h1,h2;h2,h2;h3...` I tried to do that using Lambda layer what has been explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941192/multiply-multiple-tensors-pairwise-keras But as my comment explained, I am having trouble there as well.

Comment: What does each `h` represent? What is the output shape that you would expect? I don't understand what you want to compute, maybe providing some detailed equations would help

Comment: @rvinas `h` is the timestep and I am trying to compute the concatenation. Since, it is okay to perform exhaustive concatenation the output shape will be `input_shape[0],input_shape[1]*input_shape[1],input_shape[-1]`. So this means that I have `3` timesteps and I am trying to concatenate the features. So after concatenation, I should have `?,9,2*features` [as I am concatenating so the number of features will be doubled]. Then I will multiply it with W which will give a resultant output of `?,9,features`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the concatenation operation that you described by leveraging [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in order to compute the cartesian product of the temporal dimension's indices. The call method could be coded as follows:

```py
def call(self, x):
    prod = product(range(nb_timesteps), repeat=2)
    conc_prod = []
    for i, j in prod:
        c = K.concatenate([x[:, i, :], x[:, j, :]], axis=-1)  # Shape=(batch_size, 2*nb_features)
        c_expanded = c[:, None, :]  # Shape=(batch_size, 1, 2*nb_features)
        conc_prod.append(c_expanded)
    conc = K.concatenate(conc_prod, axis=1)  # Shape=(batch_size, nb_timesteps**2, 2*nb_features)
    uit = K.dot(conc, self.W)  # W has shape 2*input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1]
    return uit  # Shape=(batch_size, nb_timesteps**2, nb_features)
```

In the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095362/concatenating-hidden-units-using-keras?noredirect=1#comment93178283_53095362) that you provided, `nb_timesteps` would be 3. Note also that the shape of the weights should be `(2*input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1])` for the dot product to be valid.

**Disclaimer**: I am not sure what you want to achieve.